# Translating "jerusalem duplici jugo gravata" into English

Tags: sentence-translation, medieval-latin, latin-to-english-translation

What does this mean?

> *jerusalem duplici jugo gravata*

Ekkehard of Aura was the monk in medieval. He departed to the crusades of 1101. This sentence is from his book Hierosolimita in RHC V, PP. 1-40.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Jerusalem, weighed down by a double yoke". But we would need more context to know what he means by this.

Comment: Thank you but this is a title.

Comment: The timing suggests that at least one of the yokes is the Islamic occupation. The crusader author suggests (less clearly) that the other one could be the destruction of the Temple or the Lord's Crucifixion. But it's just a guess. cc: @turuncu